# Choosing range when plotting data from array

Tags: data, plotting

I have loaded data from a CSV file which i want to plot in a `BarChart` but i only wish to plot `0:100` instead of the entire dataset. Is there a way to set a range for the `data`?

So far i am just plotting everything:

```
data = Import["/Users/matek/NetworkTest/without_use_in_and_out.csv", "Table"]

Show[
    BarChart[data, ChartLegends -> {"TX", "RX"}],
    ImageSize -> 600
]
```

`data`:

```
{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},...}
```

Comment: How about [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html)?

Comment: @TeakeNutma, my dataset is very big and it would be more suiteable if i could reduce it so the plotting is executed much faster. Else i need to manually manipulate the file, which is quite tedious.

Comment: Ok, assuming your dataset is of the form `data = {{tx_1, ..., tx_n}, {rx_1, ...., rx_n}}` with `n > 100`, you could do `dataTrimmed = Take[#,100]& /@ data` and plot that.

Comment: @TeakeNutma, i get following error `Take::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 100 in {0 0}. >>`

Comment: Looking at the sample data you provided, you might want to try: `data[[1;;100]]` (see Documentation Center for `Span`) (or see `Transpose` and then use @TeakeNutma's idea)

Comment: @JavaCake: please clarify: is it the domain you wish to restrict or, literally, the range?

Comment: @murray, the method PinguinDirk explained is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @JavaCake, if you want to have something like a "representative subset" of your data, you might prefer to use `RandomSample[data,100]` to pick data points randomly, rather than always the first 100. Also, depending on the heterogeneity of the data you might want to increase the sample size (to 1000, for example).

Answer (score 1):

OK, quick example: Compare the first [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart.html) with the second one where I only used the first 5 elements of `data`

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13, 14}};
BarChart[data]
BarChart[data[[;;5]]]
```